# What does the -j option do for docker-php-ext-install?

Tags: dockerfile

I have read a lot of examples for creating a dockerfile for your specific setup of PHP including installing extensions. The `docker-php-ext-install` command sometimes includes `-j$(nproc)` as an option. What exactly is happening there? I suspect the `nproc` has something to do with the number of processes?

Here's an example from https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/php#php-core-extensions

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

I'm new to docker and want to understand exactly what's happening in each step rather than blindly copying and pasting things from various examples and tutorials.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is the number of Jobs for the `make` calls contained inside the script `docker-php-ext-install` (line [53](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/docker-php-ext-install#L53) stores the option in the variable `$j` and [105-106](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/docker-php-ext-install#L105) call `make -j$j`).

The command `nproc` is giving directly to the script the number of physical thread available for your system. For example, on my system it will be reduced to:

```
make -j$(nproc) -> make -j8
```

thus it runs make with 8 parallel recipes.

From `make` [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/make):

> `-j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs]`:
> **Specifies the number of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously**. If there is more than one `-j` option, the last one is effective. If the `-j` option is given without an argument, make will not limit the number of jobs that can run simultaneously.

with more information in the `GNU make` documentation about *[parallel jobs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html)*:

> GNU make knows how to execute several recipes at once. Normally, make will execute only one recipe at a time, waiting for it to finish before executing the next. However, the `-j` or `--jobs` option tells make to **execute many recipes simultaneously**. [...] On MS-DOS, the `-j` option has no effect, since that system doesn’t support multi-processing.
>
> If the `-j` option is followed by an integer, **this is the number of recipes to execute at once**; this is called the number of job slots. If there is nothing looking like an integer after the `-j` option, there is no limit on the number of job slots. **The default number of job slots is one, which means serial execution (one thing at a time)**.

*Ideally*, if that number is equal to the number of the **physical threads** available (roughly the number of processors, or as in this case the number returned by `nproc`), you should get the **fastest compilation possible**.

> `nproc` is a linux command - see `man nproc` too. It means "number of processing units available" - your CPU Cores. You can imagine it as "Number of **processors**" [source: @tron5 comment]

You must **consider the memory available** though. For example, if you allocate 8 slots with only 1GB of RAM and the compilation of 3 simultaneous jobs fill the RAM, then when the fourth will start it will exit with an error due to insufficient memory, arresting the whole compilation process.

Comment: `nproc` is a linux command - see `man nproc` too. It means "number of processing units available" - your CPU Cores. You can imagine it as "Number of PROCessors".

Comment: Sorry @tron5, I'm missing the point of the comment... there is something wrong in the answer that I should correct?

Comment: It's all right with your answer. It was only an additional comment for others to understand "nproc" further.

Comment: Umh ok, let's give to that comment some visibility then